# Authenticate into Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm trying to access my GAE app from outside the browser.
At the moment it's Python script but I'm planning desktop C++ app.

I'm fallowing [Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).

So far I managed to access user info:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json
```

However every call to my GAE ends up with redirection to login page.

Is there a way to do authenticated calls to GAE from a script?

Please take a look at [my test code](https://gist.github.com/mrfuxi/e6c009dd85b38796a858)

**My goal:**

Use Python script on my local machine to get data (json endpoint, static file, html, whatever) from my GAE app as authenticated user.

Comment: Have you setup your GAE pages to require a login? If so, what you're seeing is expected. You don't say what your GAE app is, but I'll assume it's a REST endpoint. REST should be stateless, such that each call needs to carry its own bearer token, which your REST endpoint can then validate.

Comment: You are right, it is rest endpoint with login required in app.yaml. I'm including bearer token in the same way as for Google API. However when calling Google I'm presented with login only once.

Comment: You need to remove the login requirement from your yaml for your endpoint URLs. Remember, login=session=state whereas REST is stateless.

Comment: My point is to authenticate user to endpoint, not make it accessible to everybody. It is possible in browser so it is possible somehow.

Comment: That's why you use oauth. Each REST request carries an OAuth bearer token which your server validates to grant access to its resource.

Comment: I'm trying use oauth (fallowing the OAuth 2.o for Installed Applications), however every call to GAE ends up with redirection to login, while calls to Google Apis are fine. Should I use some specific scope?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is sort of possible using ClientLogin (deprecated) https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.

However, I have found it much easier to just have an API secret string that I use (in a header, over HTTPS) to say that the request is from an approved script.

Alternatively you can do the oauth login flow (whichever flow you want, using your own oauth app), but you don't want to use any login: tags in app.yaml, just do it entirely in your Python code.